# Laravel collection sum with pivot table's field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here my db tables:

```
**orders:**
id, customer_id, date .....etc

**packagings**
id, code, name .....

**products**
id, code, name, weight .......
```

And 2 manytomany tables with pivot :

```
**packaging_product:**
packaging_id, product_id, quantity

**packaging_order:**
packaging_id, order_id, quantity
```

To get total weight of one order i have this attribute in my order model:

```
public function getWeightAttribute()
{
    $tot_weight = 0;
    foreach ($this->packagings as $pack) {
        $tot_weight += $pack->weight * $pack->original['pivot_quantity'];
    }
    return $tot_weight; 
}
```

Where I get packaging weight from this Packaging model's attribute:

```
public function getWeightAttribute()
{
    return $this->products()->sum(DB::raw('products.weight * quantity'));
}
```

Is there an more elegant method using eloquance collections ?

Comment: I thought weight was on your products table, but you're calling it from your packagings model.

Comment: Please see edit. Thank you.